# Looking for assistance to leverage any RxJs methods when taming http calls for repeating Angular components

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular parent component that controls a list of objects, which are `spacecrafts`.
The array of objects is loaded into the parent component, I will just call it `list`, and my child components, or `cards`, receive an instance of this object each to display its information. I am using an `*NgFor` and calling the component selector and passing in `spacecraft` via `@Input`.

Note: There are two different components that use this logic, one which displays our spacecraft in a "list view" and another that allows us to display a "grid view" - similar to a desktop folder. There is a UI switch to determine which `*ngFor` loop is executed - list, or grid. They use the same list of `spacecraft` from the parent component `list`, with small amounts of additional information being fetched in each child component as needed.

When my list of `spacecraft` are returned, they contain objects/arrays within them, one of those arrays being the spacecraft's `Tasks[]`. These Spacecraft are carefully loaded in the back end (C#) and each nested entity won't necessarily have all levels of `.Include()` to bring the FULL object back, as each `Task` will have a boatload of its own entities/collections that aren't needed for these components.

Within our `Task` entity we have a collection of `Event`. (So, `Spacecrafts` have a collection of `Tasks` which contain `Events`.) We do not have a separate back end model property of `Events[]` on `Spacecraft`.
When we pull our Spacecraft query for this component, we do not include the `Events` to be nested within their `Tasks` for each Spacecraft. Doing so would really have an impact on speed and we haven't previously had a need to access an Spacecraft's events on their own. We have separate services to get an spacecraft's `Tasks[]`, in which we then include their `Events[]`.

Recently, we were given a task to display a COUNT of all `Events` existing between all `Tasks` of an `spacecraft` in our list component, separated into 3 categories of their `Severity`. We have a separate http method that allows us to grab all `Event` from the database whose property `spacecraftId` matches the id of a given `spacecraft` without having to go 3 levels deep in a LINQ query and return unneeded information and navigate through an spacecraft's Tasks. This works perfectly in every other area of the application.

What I am currently doing is loading my list of spacecraft into my `list` component, then making a separate call with a loop to obtain each spacecraft's `Events[]` and mapping each response to the spacecraft model's FRONT END only property of 'Events[]' (that I have added for this task).

It would make sense to load the Events[] data in the child components once it is received via Input(), however, doing the same call to obtain each spacecraft's Events[] when the view is flipped between the two view types is far less than ideal, because it's just a ton of data.

Ideally, I would like to have the `spacecraft[]` loaded in the parent component, so I can just re-use the same data and not have endless http calls. I hope that makes sense. My current code is below and it utilizes async/await, and it does work. I had to implement async/await, since the child components were loading before the `Events[]` were being returned to their `spacecraft` and the spacecraft were not updating once the http calls completed. (I also tried setting a boolean to flip when the last iteration of Events[] was complete - didn't work!)

List Component:

public spacecrafts: Spacecraft[] = [];

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  getSpacecraft()
}
```

```
getSpacecraft() {
  this.spacecraftService.getSpacecrafts(filters).subscribe(async res => {
      this.spacecrafts = res;
      await this.getSpacecraftEvents();
});
```

```
public async getSpacecraftEvents() {
    for (let sp of this.spacecrafts) {
      await this.spacecraftService.getEventsBySpacecraftAsync(sp.id).then(
        res => {
          sp.Events = [...res];
        }
      )
    };
    this.isLoading = false;
}
```

**service method:**

```
getEventsBySpacecraftAsync(spacecraftId: string): any {
    let params = {
      withDetails: false
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.endpoint}/${spacecraftId}/Events`, { params: params    }).toPromise();
  }
```

I don't necessarily love this, as the components controlling the view are required to wait for another component to synchronously resolve data on their behalf.
I am really trying to leverage any RxJs functionality to extract those extra `Event` calls fully into the service layer before the data is even touched in the component, but I'm not sure where to go with it. Is there a better way to do this? (Even if not RxJs, of course). I'm not able to utilize a resolver - that's another route I tried.

And, yes, I am 100% considering adopting a new back end flow to just have the spacecraft's Events[] arrive in the initial http call but I'd really love to see if any other options exist besides async/await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you not to mix promises and observables if not necessary. If you can it's better to stick to observables in angular. Therefore, I would remove async from getEventsBySpacecraftAsync and make it return observable:

```
    getEventsBySpacecraft(spacecraftId: string): any {
    let params = {
      withDetails: false
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.endpoint}/${spacecraftId}/Events`, { params: params    });
  }
```

Now in getSpacecraftEvents you are actually doing many calls for events one by one. You await for each call in a for loop. Instead you could do those calls simultanousely, which should speed up this process a lot. Also since we switched to observables in service, we do it here as well:

```
public getSpacecraftEvents() {
  forkJoin(
     this.spacecrafts.map(sp => this.spacecraftService.getEventsBySpacecraft(sp.id)))
    .subscribe(events => sp.Events = events);
  this.isLoading = false;
}
```

Instead of for loop we maped array of spacecrafts to array of observables, and joinded them together with forkJoin. After subscription, they were simultanousely requested.

It's still not perfect, because it's not awaited after you fetch spacecrafts, instead it's done in separate subscribe. So lets fix it even more, we will make it a method that will return an observable, but not subscribe to it, and later we will use it in getSpacecraft().

```
public getSpacecraftEvents() {
  return forkJoin(
    this.spacecrafts.map(sp => this.spacecraftService.getEventsBySpacecraft(sp.id)));
}
```

and getSpacecraft method:

```
getSpacecraft() {
  this.spacecraftService.getSpacecrafts(filters)
    .pipe(switchMap(spacecrafts => {
      this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
      return this.getSpacecraftEvents()
    })).subscribe(events => {
      this.spacecrafts.foreach((sp, idx) => {
        this.spacecrafts[idx].events = events.filter(e => e.spacecraftId === sp.id);
      });
    });
```

Now with switchMap we joined both series of calls in one observable that is executed in one subscribe. And event calls will execute simultanousely.

Comment: Thank you so much - I think I may be missing one thing here to tie it all together; where exactly are the Events assigned to their respective aircraft? I see that in the solution in the second code block but not in the improved method. Am I adding that in somewhere? Currently the Events are not being assigned to their aircraft, but when I log it, I see the arrays:

Comment: this.spacecraftService.getSpacecrafts(filters)
      .pipe(switchMap(sp => {
        this.spacecrafts = sp;
        return this.getSpacecraftEvents(spacecrafts)
      })).subscribe(t => {
        console.log(t);
        });

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that, sorry. You can just do it in subscribe, assuming events have a field for their spacecraft's id. I edited answer. Let me know if it does it for you

Comment: no problem! Thank you! It makes sense. Question though - in the getSpacecraft() method - are we sending back the response 'spacecraft' into the return this.getSpacecraftEvents(spacecraft)? (rather than our this.spacecraft).... I'm assuming that's a yes. I think I'm confused there because in getSpacecraftEvents(spacecrafts), we reference this.spacecrafts, rather than the param spacecrafts.

Comment: another thing that popped up with the this.spacecrafts = this.spacecrafts.forEach() - "Type 'void' is not assignable to type Spacecraft[] , so I'm trying to set up the loop a different way. It also isn't loving the subscribe response "events" - saying that it's unknown and "filter" does not exist on type 'unknown'. Brain is fried! Lol

Comment: I tried adding a return of :any to getSpacecraftEvents() (with the forkJoin), but then it assumes that the property "spacecraftId" doesn't exist on type 'unknown' .

Comment: Ah, sorry for all those mistakes. 
So first, for spacecrafts parameter in this.getSpacecraftEvents(spacecraft), you can remove it. My first thought was to use it, but this.spacecraft can just be used instead. 

Second thing is that this.spacecrafts = this.spacecrafts.forEach(). Assignment is actually unnecessary, events are assigned in foreach loop. So it should be just this.spacecrafts.forEach().

And for the forkJoin it's weird, normally events in subscribe should be array of whatever is returned from spacecraftService.getEventsBySpacecraft's api call. Can you try to console log them?

Comment: You can try to specify return types from your methods. 
For example getEventsBySpacecraft(spacecraftId: string): Observable<Event[]>

Comment: I'm so sorry I forgot to comment back! I just wanted to say thank you for your help on this - I was able to make this work!!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways of doing this:
You can create an intermediate component that loads the event data and switches between the grid and list component without recalling your server every time you switch views, or, you can use map to iterate over all spacecrafts and attach them the event data, something like:

```
this.spacecraftsService.getSpacecrafts()
.pipe(map(spacecrafts: Spacecraft[] => {
    spacecrafts.map(spacecraft: Spacecraft => {
        const events = /* some logic to fetch the events */
        return { ...spacecraft, events } 
    })
}))
```

There are more efficient ways to the second approach based on how much you know RxJS, but this illustrates the point.